# How to organize a purchased "theme" composed of related javascript, css and image files into a Rails 3.1 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, themes, asset-pipeline

So migrating an rails app to 3.1 and having all kinds of headaches related to the new assets pipeline functionality.  The biggest problem has to do with properly organizing a theme purchased from themeforest.net into the application so things work in development, test and production.

The theme, like most I assume, contains inter-related javascript, css and images.  In my Rails 3.0 app it was structured like this:

```
public
    my_theme
        css
        images
        javascript
```

Given the new assets pipeline, what is the best way to organize the theme in 3.1?

As files in the individual directories (css, images, javascript) reference each other, I'm hoping there is a way to port it over into a 3.1 app without have to do much if any modification the actual content of those theme files.

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit the question and provide a list of the files inside the css and javascript folders? With that info I can have a good shot at helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the pipeline basically works is that it compiles assets from the 3 directories mentioned in the documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html (`lib/assets`,`app/assets`,`vendor/assets`), (your purchased theme could go in `vendor/assets`).

It then takes each sudirectory in those directories that and puts it in public/assets where it becomes available.

So you are not restricted to `vendor/assets/javascripts`, etc.  that is just a suggestion.

I would suggest putting them here:
`vendor/assets/theme_name_javascripts`,`vendor/assets/theme_name_images`, etc

If your images are referenced by: `images/sprite.png`, then you have to put it in:
`vendor/assets/theme_name_images/images/sprite.png`

Comment: What changes if any are required to your CSS files that reference images, e.g. "background-image: url('../../img/build/header_bg2.png');"

Comment: Just get rid of all `../../` 's   Then put the image in the `vendor/assets/theme_name_images/img/build/` directory.  That way you should have to do a minimum of editing and moving.  BTW this will not work if you put your assets to a CDN.  In that case you have to use SCSS files.

Comment: is not easier to create /vendor/assets/theme_name/ and put js, css, images on that folder? is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I've done it:

- create a vendor/my_theme directory
- copy the theme directories (css, js, images, themes) into vendor/my_theme
- created a config/initializers/my_theme.rb file, with content:

> ```
> HashtagifyPro::Application.configure do
>   config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "my_theme")
> end
> ```

- change the css and js links in the html like this: from ./css/all.css to /assets/css/all.css, and ./js/my.js to /assets/js/my.js

And that's it!

By the way, if you don't want to pre process your theme assets with sprockets, it is perfectly legit to leave your theme in the public/ directory

Comment: What changes if any are required to your CSS files that reference images, e.g. "background-image: url('../../img/build/header_bg2.png');"